# How to send h2(http/2) connection preface

Tags: h2, http2

I'm writing a simple program for testing how http/2 connection work.
I read the RFC specification from:
https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html

I was able to successfully connect and use ALPN to negotiate h2.
After the server accepts to use h2.
I sent

```
PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n
```

Which was described in the **RFC7540** specification. After this I was supposed to send a **SETTINGS** frame which I don't really know what to send, I also read about the **SETTINGS** frame in the **RFC7540** but was unable to understand.
Could anyone please just send me an example of what to do next.
Sorry for my bad English and Thank you in advance.!

Comment: Hi Muhammad, is it possible to share the code / commands that you are using to send messages to the server. This should help someone answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the purpose of getting you started, you can send an empty SETTINGS frame.

If you look at the [frame format](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#FrameHeader) and at the [SETTINGS frame definition](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#SETTINGS), you will realize that for an empty SETTINGS frame you have to send these bytes:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00       # payload length (3 bytes)
0x04 0x00            # type (1 byte) flags (1 byte)
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  # stream id (4 bytes)
```

You can send these bytes right after the [client preface bytes](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#ConnectionHeader)

In summary, send the preface bytes:

`0x505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a`

and then the empty SETTINGS frame bytes:

`0x000000040000000000`

Comment: This was really helpful.. thank you so much